# What are Moderator Tools and what am I supposed to do with them now I have access?

Tags: discussion, support

This question will probably get down-voted because it looks like I haven't done any research.  Trouble is, having gone through the obvious links on the Site Information, I am none the wiser.  I confess I'm a bit of a dunce when it comes to interrogating web sites, but how difficult does this have to be?  Where do I find out what this privilege means?

Comment: Sometimes simple questions need to be addressed! +1.

Comment: Ah, the penny has finally dropped!  I'm a bit slow off the mark sometimes.....

Comment: Congratulations!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the site tour thing [that explains it](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools)

It's not 100% of the moderator tools (i.e you don't get the flag handling stuff), but it's a good chunk of what a trusted community member would need to help moderate.